# Настрока компилятора в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Всем добрый день. Следующая. Проблема. Использую QtCreator 4.11 (Qt5.14) с компилятором MSVC2015 64бит, компилятор выдает слишком много ненужных мне ворнингов, например, предупреждение: noexcept specifications are incompatible with C++98, или предупреждение: in-class initialization of non-static data members is incompatible with C++98. Которые для меня абсолтюно неактуальны. Как я могу настроить компилятор, какие ворнинги мне выдавать, а какие нет. Спрашиваю по причине того, что ранее работал с компилятором MinGW и он такие ворнинги не выдавал, а сейчас четверть проекта подчеркнута красным и это нервирует. Пытался гуглить, но решения своей проблемы не нашел.

Comment: Надо не предупреждения подавлять, а выставить к требуемую версию стандарта. в VS начиная с 2017 поддерживается с++17 и частично C++14

Comment: У меня сейчас используется MSVC2015, в .pro файле прописано использовать CONFIG += c++11. Что мне еще нужно сделать чтоб компилятор перестал ругаться на несовместимость с С++98?

Comment: Перейти хотя бы на vs2017 и на 17 стандарт. 11 в студии так и не был реализован

Comment: Нашел решение данной проблемы. Заходим в инструменты-параметры-С++-модель кода. И прописываем свой набор флагов, например, мне понравился следующий набор: -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-unused-macros -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-global-constructors -Wno-gnu-2ero-variadic-macro-arguments -Wno-dacumentation -Wno-shadow -Wno-missing-prototypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение данной проблемы. Заходим в инструменты-параметры-С++-модель кода. И прописываем свой набор флагов, например, мне понравился следующий набор: -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-unused-macros -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-global-constructors -Wno-gnu-2ero-variadic-macro-arguments -Wno-dacumentation -Wno-shadow -Wno-missing-prototypes –

Comment: а как вы получаете vcxproj? из pro-файла с помощью qmake? тогда все эти -W пропадут при запуске qmake